# fast retrieval of (void *) memory block

Tags: c++, c

I have a system that returns a void* to a memory block. This memory block stores contiguous data records of different types(int,char,double etc.) and gives the number of bytes of each field in each record.I essentially look up the type of the record and get the value of the record. To retrieve all the records, I do

```
switch(type)

{

   case 'int' : \*(int*)(ptr+index)

   case 'char': \*(char*)(ptr+index)

}
```

When I have to go through 300000 records this is taking a lot of time.Is there a faster way to go through all the records?

Comment: Can you please post (and format properly) real code?  This cannot be correct.

Comment: Define "a lot of time." Are we talking microseconds or seconds? If the latter, then it's very likely that you're swapping memory to disk, and will only resolve with more RAM. 300,000 records is not that big, and simply accessing the memory for those 300,000 records should happen extremely quickly.

Comment: seconds. In each switch case I'm appending the value to an ostringstream. Would that take significantly longer?

Comment: `C` or `C++`? I believe this answer can be very different for the different languages ...

Comment: @Rajesh: your code is not legitimate C or C++. The answer, however, depends. It depends on what you are doing with values, where you getting this block of memory from, etc. How do you know that switch statement is a bottleneck? Have you used a profiler? I simply cannot believe switch is a problem.

Comment: I checked the execution time...the switch statement takes 15 seconds for 2,46,000 records

Comment: @Rajesh: can you post the declaration of `type` (the variable you're using for the switch)? Is it an `int`? If it is, what is the value of `(int)'abc'`?

Comment: They are variables declared in an enum > case kTYPE_SEQU4: is an int32 and the switch is... switch(cType[col]) which is basically an array of types of the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a single block can be of multiple types that can only be resolved at runtime, you will have to dispatch to handlers in a `switch` statement. Note that:

1. `union`s are usually used in C for such things to save space
2. `switch` statements are very fast and translate to constant-time lookup tables

Comment: its actually continuous memory of various types..like int,char,int,double...so it would be 4 bytes,1 byte,4 bytes,8 bytes etc

Comment: @Eli, switch statements are not guaranteed to be constant-time lookup tables. It depends on whether compiler can optimize it or not.

Comment: @Vlad: I assumed that for the simple case required by the author (dispatching with `switch` on an `enum` or small integer) today's compilers will optimize it

Comment: @Rajesh: given a stream of binary data, how do you know the next 4 bytes are an int or a beginning of a double?

Comment: I'm given the starting point of each record and its datatype/size

Comment: @Rajesh: then, as I said in the answer, apart from somewhat invalid C syntax your general direction is correct. `switch` on the type and get the record into the correct type of variable

Comment: @Rajesh: How are you fetching the `type` from the data? Maybe you have a Schlemiel painter problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly -- I assume you're going through each record, sortof saying "for each record `i`, if its type is 'char' then access the record at location `i`".

If you know how many records you have to access in advance, can't you just cache them all first?

If I'm completely off track forgive me for not understanding your point.

Comment: cache?..they are already in memory..I'm given a pointer to the first location

Answer (score 0):

Your comments finally gave enough information to answer the question: you're writing to an `ostringstream`. Which means that you're probably doing a lot of string manipulation inside your switch. Figure out how to optimize this, and your performance problems should go away.

(to convince yourself this is the case, simply comment out all code that references the stream and run your program again)

Comment: The only operation I do is reading into a ostringstream which i use as a means of serialization to send over a socket. Are there better options for this?